# Android: create a zip file split in chunks

Tags: android, zip

i've a problem: i create a zip file that is over 50mb. Now, sending it requires too much time, so i would like to split it into chunks of 5 mb each (or less).
Does anyone of u knows how to do it?
is there a specific funcion of a zip library or i've to do something different?

Thanks

Comment: Splitting in 5 is not that difficult. But on the other side: do you have a program/app to glue them together?

Comment: nope, i will have to write that as well. 
using this code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431945/split-and-join-back-a-binary-file-in-java)  works  for splitting.. i've to check if works for glueing